# QGIS Symbology - Size & colour for different variables in one symbol

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology

I'm a QGIS beginner, and want to create a map with the following conditions.

I have a few cities as a shapefile and my attribute table looks something like this:

| CITY NAME | VARIABLE A "green" | VARIABLE B "yellow" | VARIABLE C "red" | VARIABLE D "black" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 7 | 5 | 4 |
| B | 7 | 10 | 20 | 4 |
| C | 20 | 5 | 7 | 5 |

I want to show the values for each city similar to the image below - one single symbol that shows  my four variables in their colour and the size depending on their value.

[image: stacked circles, red, yellow, green]

I know how to apply data-defined size & colour changes for a single variable, but how can I generate multiple variables for one symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple `simple markers` to the `single symbol`.

Set the colors as you wish, and override the size by clicking the `epsilon` icon and by summing the values of the variables before it. For the 1st color, the size will be `A` and for the 4th it would be `A+B+C+D`

[image]